# Route to specific product details page from mapped product list

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Dropdown from './components/Dropdown/Dropdown';
import Header from './components/Header/Header.jsx'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Main from './pages/Main';
import Catalog from './pages/Catalog';
import About from './pages/About';
import Contacts from './pages/Contacts';
import CarProductDetails from './components/СarItems/CarProductDetails';
import Error from './pages/Error'


function App() {
  const [dropState, setDropState] = useState(false);
  const handleCloseDrop = () => setDropState(false);
  const handleOpenDrop = () => setDropState(true);

  return (
    <>
<Router>
    <Header openDrop={handleOpenDrop}/>
    <Navbar />
    <Dropdown showDrop={dropState} closeDrop={handleCloseDrop} />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='/contacts' element={<Contacts />} />
      <Route path='/catalog' element ={<Catalog />} />
      <Route path='/catalog/:productId' element={<CarProductDetails />}/>
      <Route path='*' element={<Error />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer /> 
</Router>
  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My ProductPage

```
const CarSectionItem = () => {
    return (
      carsData.map((product) => (
      <CarItem key={product.id}>
        //*some code*//
        <CarButtonLink to={`/catalog/${product.id}`} target="_blank">
          {product.buttonLabel}
        </CarButtonLink>
      </CarItem>
      ))
    )


};
export default CarSectionItem;
```

Component that includes Car Item with other components:

```
import React from "react";
import { CarsSectionContainer, CarsContainer } from "./CarsSectionElements";
import CarsFilter from "./CarsFilter/CarsFilter";
import CarSectionItem from "./СarSectionItem/CarSectionItem";


const CarsSection = () => {


  return (
    <CarsSectionContainer>
      <CarsFilter/>
      <CarsContainer>
        <CarSectionItem />
      </CarsContainer>
    </CarsSectionContainer>
  );
};

export default CarsSection;
```

My ProductItemDetails

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import carsData from "../data/CarsData";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";


const CarProductDetails = () => {
  // const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const thisProduct = carsData.find((product) => product.id === productId);
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>{thisProduct.title}</h1>
    <h1>{thisProduct.price}</h1>
    </div>

  );
}
export default CarProductDetails;
```

My Data File

```
const carsData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: '$80 000',
    brand: 'Genesis',
    title: "text",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: '$80 000',
    brand: 'Toyota',
    title: "text1",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    price: '$80 000',
    brand: 'Hyundai',
    title: "text2",
  },
];

export default carsData;
```

I'm trying to map product items in my product list and get a specific link for each of product opened on a new page.

But when i click on the button it gives me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'brand')
```

```
The above error occurred in the <CarProductDetails> component:
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'brand')
```

I was following these guides:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-product-detail-pages-dynamic-links-tmcjc?file=/src/App.js
and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVE6cx3UEpM but it doesn't work for me.

What should i do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem in CarProductDetails component.

When you get url params from useParams hook, it's always be `string`.  See [docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params), type declaration section.

And in CarProductDetails component, you're trying to compare productId (type `string`) with product.id (type `number`) with strong equal operator (`===`). As a result, you got `undefined`.

Try to change your compare function to this one:

`const thisProduct = carsData.find((product) => product.id === parseInt(productId));`